# How to obtain desired output?

Tags: python, phylogenetics, fasta, phylogeny

I am working on a project using the following command within `nano`:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import sys
import re 


    fasta_file = (sys.argv[1])
    for myfile in SeqIO.parse(fasta_file, "fasta"):
      if len(myfile) > 250:
       gene_id = myfile.id
       mylist = re.match(r"H149xcV_\w+_\w+_\w+", gene_id)
       print (">"+mylist.group(0))   # edited from list to mylist
```

and its providing with the following outout:

```
>H149xcV_Fge342_r3_h2_d1
>H149xcV_bTr423_r3_h2_d1
>H149xcV_kN893_r3_h2_d1
>H149xcV_DNp021_r3_h2_d1
>H149xcV_JEP3324_r3_h2_d1
>H149xcV_SRt424234_r3_h2_d1
```

How can I change my command so that it provides me with the desired format and only the **UNIQUE** gene id's:

```
>H149xcV_Fge342_r3_h2
>H149xcV_bTr423_r3_h2
>H149xcV_kN893_r3_h2
>H149xcV_DNp021_r3_h2
>H149xcV_JEP3324_r3_h2
>H149xcV_SRt424234_r3_h2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its easy replace `match` with `sub` but please stop using `list` as a variable ... mylist is fine.

This might work

```
   mylist = re.sub(r'H149xcV_\w+_\w+_\w+', gene_id)
```

otherwise

```
myregex = re.compile('_\w+\s+.*') 
fastaid = myregex.sub('', myfile)
```

OR from @MaximilianPress

```
myregex2 = re.compile('_\w+\n') # or myregex2 = re.compile('_\w+$')
fastaid2 = myregex.sub('\n', myfile) # or fasaid2 = myregex.sub('', myfile)
```

The above will work ... As with all my code I never proof it ..

Comment: Hi @andnowmywatchbegins thats easy just use dictionary to remove the duplicates ... its been answered several times on the site. Please remember accept/upvote stuff.

Answer (score 0):

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import sys
import re 

unique = []
fasta_file = (sys.argv[1])
for myfile in SeqIO.parse(fasta_file, "fasta"):
    if len(myfile) > 250:
        gene_id = myfile.id
        if gene.id not in unique:
            unique.append(gene.id)
            mylist = re.match(r"H149xcV_\w+_\w+_\w+", gene_id)
            print (">"+mylist.group(0))
```

let me know if it works I am learning too